# Java - int WON'T overflow with hashing

Tags: java, hash, overflow, hashcode

So I'm just getting into Object-Oriented Programming in Java, and I have to make this hashed dictionary. I'm supposed to hash a name with a algorithm and return the hashed value. The lab said to do

```
int n = s.length();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
hash = g * hash + s.charAt(i);
```

where g = 31, s = firstName + lastName;

and I looked at this and put it into code. What I wrote was

```
public int hashCode()     // part of the Name class
{
    int h = 0;
    String bothNames = first + last;
    for (int i = 0; i < bothNames.length(); i++) {
        h += bothNames.charAt(i)*Math.pow(g, bothNames.length() - i-1);
    }
    return h;
}
```

Now, when I ran this code on something like Name testName = new Name("Wayne", "Gretzky");
and printed out testName.hashCode(), I almost always got the 32 bit integer limit back, which meant that it wasn't overflowing. However, when I changed the for loop to

```
for (int i = 0; i < bothNames.length(); i++) {
    h = g*h + bothNames.charAt(i);
}
```

all of a sudden, it was overflowing again. I don't really understand why this would happen. The two hash functions should be the same. Why wouldn't h overflow in the first case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "The two hash functions should be the same." How do you figure that?

Comment: Well, the original hash function was h = u_0 g^(n - 1) + u_1 g^(n - 2) + … + u_(n - 2) g + u_(n - 1), and both of these should do the same thing, one gets the terms one by one, which was my original one, and the new one does it a little differently. I worked through both of them and it looks like they should be the same, u_k * g^(n-k) is a term in both of the hash functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
h += bothNames.charAt(i)*Math.pow(g, bothNames.length() - i-1)
```

The `pow` method is returning a large `double` value.  Which you multiply by an integer to give you a larger `double` value.  Then the `h += ...` does a *primitive narrowing* conversion from `double` to `int`.

The `double` to `int` conversion is *defined* to convert any floating point value value greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (!).

The solution will be to compute the g<sup>k</sup> using integer arithmetic; e.g. using the recurrence:

> g<sup>0</sup> = 1
>
> g<sup>k</sup> = g * g<sup>k - 1</sup> (for k > 0).

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the following line:

```
h += bothNames.charAt(i) * Math.pow(g, bothNames.length() - i - 1);
```

Considering the nature of [compound assignment operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2), this is equivalent to:

```
h = (int)(h + (bothNames.charAt(i) * Math.pow(g, bothNames.length() - i - 1)));
```

This would be fine, if it were not for the fact that [`Math.pow`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,double)) returns a `double`. Taking regular widening rules into account:

```
h = (int)(intValue + (intValue * doubleValue))
h = (int)(intValue + doubleValue)
h = (int)(doubleValue)
```

The last `doubleValue` gets narrowed to an `int`. If the string is long enough, the `doubleValue` will exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE` from the first iteration.